# manager-osx to run XAMPP Apache server shows error after upgrade to macOS Ventura

Tags: xampp, macos-ventura

Today I upgrade my `Mac OS` to the latest version `Ventura` and found `manager-osx` which runs the XAMPP Apache Server and MySql Database stops working and gives the below error when we click on it.

[image]

How can we resolve this?

Comment: Please [edit] to add a transcription of your  images of text into actual text. [See here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541) for why. Please also specify what versions of XAMPP Apache Server and MySql Database you are using.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is pretty simple that I have not found anywhere and explored myself by chance.

We can run `manager-osx` which is also located under `xamppfiles` folder as shown in the screenshot below.

[image]

I am able to run it from there without any issues. Both Apache Server and MySql are running after clicking on `manager-osx` icon located under `xamppfiles` folder as shown in the screenshot below.

[image]

Hope it will help someone in future! Thanks